# How to make POST request using retrofit2 where one of the form-data fields is a file?

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

Using retrofit2 I want to make a png upload request to my API. It has to be a POST request and png is passed as form-data field "img". I tested my API using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) and everything works but now I want to make this request from android app using retrofit2. Is this library even capable of making such request?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload an image:

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyApp/test.jpg");

RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                            .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                            .addPart(Headers.of("Content-Disposition", 
                                     "form-data; name=\"image\";filename=\"" 
                                     + file.getName() + "\""),
                              RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JPG, file))
                            .build();

// Todo: replace with your own interface e.g. apiClient
Call<ResponseBody> call = apiClient.uploadImage(requestBody);

call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        Log.v("Upload", "success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
   }
});
```

Example interface and required endpoint method defined:

```
public interface ApiClient {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/content")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part("image") RequestBody image);
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. I was struggling with this for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try [Fast Android Networking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking) library for that as it is simple and fast android networking library. I have created this library that is built on top of OKHttp and have more features and customization than Retrofit.

in your gradle file add depedencies

compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:0.0.1'

```
    File file = new File(imagePath);
    AndroidNetworking.upload(url)
                     .addMultipartFile("img",file) 
                     .setTag("uploadTest")
                     .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                     .build()
                     .setUploadProgressListener(new UploadProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(long bytesUploaded, long totalBytes) {
                        // do anything with progress 
                        }
                     })
                     .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // do anything with response                
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(ANError error) {
                        // handle error 
                        }
                     }); 
}
```

Comment: I cannot use another library. I'm already using retrofit2 everywhere in my app. To replace a library would be a burden.

Comment: @Egis : Ok Bro , I will try to solve it by retrofit and inform you soon. Just wanted to have some feedback on https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking .